# Can a US state opt to become a territory without leaving the nation as a whole?

Tags: united-states, secession, territory, statehood, texas

This relates to an item legislated by the Texas republican party recently. Overlooking the more regressive and dangerous items, and the frivolous and inconsequential items, they are also throwing the idea around of leaving the United States. This is not legally possible.

Texas has a history of threatening to do this every fifteen years or so, for better or for worse. Aside from legality, it would be a massive inconvenience for parties on both sides of the border, and leave them with substantial debt which I do not believe that they deserve to face alone; but then, I am not specifically a Texan.

If they did secede from the union, they would lose a lot of Federal resources which Texas has come to depend on, along with social security, armament, medicare, and any number of additional federal programs. This would also result in the retrieval of a massive amount of infrastructure and federal hardware from Texas, which would not be instantaneous or easy. That said, a lot of us would be happy to wish them well and let them go, given proper congressional management of the issue, but it just can't reasonably be done.

As precedent, in 1864 (Texas v. White), the Supreme Court determined that the constitution did not permit states to unilaterally secede from the union, and the agreements made with the defunct Confederated States of America (including by Texas) were null.

So, I'm wondering, if the Republic of Texas is tired of being a state, can we just allow them to become a territory instead? They would still benefit from a lot of the federal aid they need, but they would no longer be represented in congress as a state. They would additionally receive advantages akin to Puerto Rico, like not having to pay federal income taxes. Is there precedent against this, since they would not be leaving the nation?

Would this interfere with the legislation of Texas v. White, or any other unmentioned case?

Comment: They would also have to pay their fair share of the national debt which I don't think they have any possibility of doing.

Comment: Is anyone in that conference seriously proposing they do just this, i.e. become a territory? There's no real advantage as it involves giving up their Senate seats etc. Looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxation_in_Puerto_Rico there are more caveats to not paying federal taxes than one might sumize.

Comment: @Fizz No, but given the nature of that conference, perhaps they should be. It's certainly more reasonable.

Comment: ***Is there precedent** for a US state opting to become a territory without leaving the nation as a whole?*

Comment: "They would additionally receive advantages akin to Puerto Rico, like not having to pay federal income taxes." That's the current system for all the territories with meaningful populations, but the territories are handled individually; whether or not a Texas territory paid income taxes would be handled legislatively. After all, D.C. is not a state and elects no federal legislators with voting power (it just gets three presidential electoral votes that no one campaigns for, and a single representative in the House with no power in floor votes), yet it's still subject to income tax.

Comment: What do you mean by *the retrieval of a massive amount of infrastructure and federal hardware from Texas*?  Seceding states do not usually hand over federal property to the government of the country they're leaving from.

Comment: @gerrit Well in this scenario they would be returning a lot of material, currently in Texas, on the federal dollar. Military bases, as an example. I'm not interested in speculating on an armed insurrection on a politics stack exchange, that's kind of outside of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's what the Constitution says about territorial changes and states:

(Article IV, Section 3, emphasis mine)

> New States may be admitted by the Congress into this Union; but no new
> States shall be formed or erected within the Jurisdiction of any other
> State; nor any State be formed by the Junction of two or more States,
> or parts of States, without the Consent of the Legislatures of the
> States concerned **as well as of the Congress**.
>
> **The Congress shall have Power to dispose of and make all needful Rules
> and Regulations respecting the Territory or other Property belonging
> to the United States**; and nothing in this Constitution shall be so
> construed as to Prejudice any Claims of the United States, or of any
> particular State.

In other words, changes in the makeup/territory of existing US States cannot be made *unilaterally* by states (or by Congress). Congress must concur, as must the state(s) in question.

Here's the clarification (decision) made by SCOTUS in Texas v. White:

> When, therefore, Texas became one of the United States, she entered
> into an indissoluble relation. All the obligations of perpetual union,
> and all the guaranties of republican government in the Union, attached
> at once to the State. The act which consummated her admission into the
> Union was something more than a compact; it was the incorporation of a
> new member into the political body. And it was final. The union
> between Texas and the other States was as complete, as perpetual, and
> as indissoluble as the union between the original States. There was no
> place for reconsideration, or revocation, except through revolution,
> **or through consent of the States**.

Again, seems pretty dang definitive here. Congress has to agree.

Now if Texas can convince Congress to go along, sure. As a neighboring Oklahoman, I'll confess I've had a few moments where I wouldn't be sad to see them go. But as a matter of policy that seems highly unlikely.

Comment: The open question is whether Congress is allowed to agree.

Comment: @ohwilleke - Both the constitution and White flatly stated that Congress agreeing is how such changes are made. In the absence of something at the same level saying its not an option period, I'm not sure why there would still be a question.

Comment: The Constitution says absolutely nothing directly about a state ceasing to be a state. Any statement in White on point would be dicta as Congress didn't approve, and in context, the language in White is quite unclear as applied in this manner.

Answer (score 29):

The "advantages" of being a territory are meager at best, and countermanded by a serious overriding problem: You have to follow federal law, but you have no say in what that law says. You don't get to vote for President or for anyone in Congress, and your territorial (local) system of government is defined by the terms of your [organic act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organic_act) (a federal law that you don't get to vote on). It is inconceivable to me that any state, let alone such a proud state as Texas, would be willing to accept such a serious derogation of their sovereignty for some minor financial benefits. It would be seen as a serious humiliation, not something you would ask for.

Comment: That wasn't my question sir—I agree with you on this except that they're already voting to secede. That is arguably much, much worse, particularly for a resource-starved region like Texas. I'm, at least academically, looking for a potential mitigation of that problem and a milder step if they think they want Texan independence. The question was not "should they secede", but what else could they potentially do instead?

Comment: @MichaelMacha: Territorial status is a "worst of both worlds" solution. They want to secede in order to *increase* their sovereign power, and you are proposing that they give up more of it.

Comment: I can think of no stochastic universe in which leaving the United States as a whole would increase their sovereign power over becoming a territory. They take 15% of our total Federal Tax tab as it stands. Again, this is about mitigation.

Comment: @MichaelMacha: Money is not sovereignty, and in fact money has nothing to do with sovereignty. Sovereignty is about the power to pass (and enforce) whatever laws you want, as well as various other government functions such as entering into foreign relations. Texas's status as a state restricts its ability to do those things, because its sovereign powers are shared with the federal government. Territorial status would impose equal or greater restrictions in just about every way possible.

Comment: The question was "can", not "should". I'm looking for legal precedent, not an opinion.

Comment: @MichaelMacha: It's a [frame challenge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263672/275243). You are asking about something which Texas does not want to do.

Comment: No it isn't. This is something that Texas Republicans are voting on, right now. We haven't addressed the core of the question once, so please leave it alone. https://www.ksat.com/news/local/2022/06/21/texas-republicans-call-for-vote-on-secession-in-new-party-platform-thats-not-legally-possible-experts-say/

Comment: @MichaelMacha You're showing some Texans want **secession**, not to lose their status as a state and become a territory. The point of this answer is to say that becoming a territory is not something that would appeal to Texan secessionists; they would not see it as a "milder form of independence". It isn't relevant hat **you** see secession as a bad idea for Texas and **you** see territoriality as "less bad"; Texan secessionists themselves would not see territoriality as giving them any of the things they want from independence, so they wouldn't go for it as a compromise solution.

Comment: You know, I may be new to this stack, but on most stacks we try to focus on the question and resolve them through citations and reasoning, not throwing opinions and speculations. I have done neither. I'm not discussing my opinion at all—I'm asking if it's feasibly possible, and how a real concern can be managed and mitigated in a professional fashion. That's it. That's all. Legal precedent, historical references, you know, actual political science. I don't *care* what Texans want, or whether they would consider it—I'm talking theory. If you can't understand that, please don't comment.

Comment: @Ben: yeah, this Q is about par with "can the US sell Alaska back to Russia" in terms of motivation. (As in, why would they want to do that?)

Comment: @MichaelMacha Frame challenge answers (i.e. "the premises of your question are wrong, so a straight answer wouldn't be as useful as you think") are on-topic here in my understanding, and this answer seems to be an attempt at one. This answer existing doesn't preclude other answers existing, such as ohwilleke's. I only commented because it looked form the discussion that you weren't understanding what it was really trying to say; if that's mistaken I apologise! If you understand it and don't find it useful, the recommended action would be to downvote it and move on.

Comment: My DVs are reserved for being factually incorrect. @MichaelMacha - you put the important part in the last sentence of the fifth paragraph: *precedent*. And the first word of the title is *can* which people are interpreting as *could* or *would*. Ask, *is* or *has there been*.

Comment: @Kevin: I feel like your answer would be improved by copy/pasting select portions of some of the comments you've made above, especially, "Sovereignty is about the power...every way possible."

Answer (score 17):

There is no constitutional mechanism for doing so, and it has never been attempted. The conventional wisdom in the legal community is that the U.S. Civil War resolved this issue and that it is not allowed.

But, no speculative legal issue of first impression can ever be definitively resolved with great certainty.

State lines can be redrawn with the consent of the affected states and the U.S. Congress, and some future decision makers could decide that this process would also be constitutionally sufficient to allow a state to be demoted to a territory or to secede.

Alternatively, one could argue that it takes an Article V Constitutional Amendment to which the state in question consents.

Comment: *The conventional wisdom in the legal community is that the U.S. Civil War resolved this issue and that it is not allowed.* any references for this?

Comment: @StuartF - [Texas vs. White](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_v._White) Seems particularly relevant here. Not sure why the post needs to go into that though, since that info is already in the question.

Comment: @StuartF I've seen it so stated by both courts and scholars but lack the time to get a lnk.

Comment: @T.E.D., Texas v. White is about *unilateral* secession.  I'm not aware of any rulings regarding secession where all parties agreed to it.

Comment: @Mark Agreed. It would be a question of first impression because it has never happened.

Comment: @Mark - The Constitution seems pretty clear in the putative case where both parties agree (see my answer). And of course legal precedent for anything likely to go up to SCOTUS isn't what it used to be, so I'm not sure its worth bemoaning the fact that we don't have any.